# Horizontal menu css with horizontal sub menu

Tags: css

I hope there is someone who can help me follow.:
See e.g.:  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PhuBQ/)
Drop Down menu, I want to be visible all time and displayed horizontal right instead of vertical.

Comment: Please describe what you need help with.

Comment: do you mean something like [this](http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/386_navigation/top-nav-demo/index.html), or more like [that one](http://www.alistapart.com/d/horizdropdowns/horizontal2.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example: http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/csstopmenu.shtml

By the way, how do I add a comment to a question like other users have done above?

Comment: You can only comment when your reputation is high enough. http://stackoverflow.com/privileges